# How do i intercept all the http request made from application using dojo framework

Tags: javascript, http-headers, dojo, interceptor

I have an application that uses dojo framework. I need to add csrf token in the header to all the http request made. How do i do that in dojo?

Comment: Do you use axios ?

Comment: No.. just using dojo. I tried using dojo aspects but was not successful

Comment: Does this helps ? https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/notify.html#:~:text=dojo%2Frequest%2Fnotify%20is%20a,emitted%20by%20the%20Request%20API.

Comment: Does this intercept all the request made from anywhere in the application? I am looking something similat to httpIntreceptor in angular

Comment: I am not a Dojo user, I just read the doc. You must try to know